# reverse axis in R

Tags: r, reverse

I am trying to plot simple picture like this, using 3 values - xyz loaded from textfile.

[image]

Now I need X-axis to go from biggest numbers to lowest (now are biggest numbers on the right, I need them on the left), so that two zeros meet in the same corner. I am using this simple code:

```
xyz <- read.table("excel")
scatterplot3d(xyz,xlim = c(0, 100000))
xyz
```

I have tried "rev" with no success. Picture always looks the same. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Sample data stored in file named "excel":

```
8884    20964   2
8928    5   1
9033    6   2
9261    61307   1
9435    64914   3
9605    5   2
9626    7   3
9718    5   3
10117   48941   7
10599   399 9
20834   5802    10
21337   3   8
21479   556 8
```

I want my 0,0,0 point to be in right front down corner.

Comment: As shown, your 0,0,0 point is in the left front corner.  Is that not what you want?  A reproducible example would be helpful (use some made up data) and also, can you map V1, V2, V3 to x, y and z?  That way we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, I added sample data and also explanation - I want my 0,0,0 point to be in right front down corner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose an angle between >90 and <270

```
   scatterplot3d(xyz,xlim = c(0, 100000),angle=ang)
```

for example:

```
z <- seq(-10, 10, 0.01)
x <- cos(z)+1
y <- sin(z)+1
scatterplot3d(x, y, z, highlight.3d=TRUE, col.axis="blue",angle=120,
              col.grid="lightblue", main="scatterplot3d - 1", pch=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I adjusted it and it works. However I am still curious how to do it my way. If there is not answer on this, I will mark yours as an aswer. My code: scatterplot3d(xyz, highlight.3d=TRUE, col.axis="blue",angle=150,
              col.grid="lightblue", ylim=c(0,100000), main="scatterplot3d - 1", pch=20)

Answer (score 4):

if you don't mind using cloud function from lattice package, then you can simply put the arguments of xlim in reversed order:

```
require(lattice)

xyz <- read.table( text = 
"0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5")

cloud(V3~V1*V2,data = xyz, scales = list(arrows = FALSE), drape = T, xlim = c(3,0))
```

You can rotate the axes with `screen` parameter to make it look the way you like.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this does not plot anything for me :/ (I copy pasted your source code)